# Jump sequence for placeholders in yasnippet not working in org-property blocks

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, yasnippet, quote

I use the [yasnippet](https://github.com/capitaomorte/yasnippet) bundle and it works like charm.

When I want to include placeholders in a PROPERTIES section of an org-document it is not working.

Here's the snipper:

```
#type: snippet
# --
:PROPERTIES:
${1: :var: name="$2"}
${3: :var: url="$4"}
:END:
$0
```

What this does is to define 2 optional variables, "name" and "url".

When calling `(yas-tryout-snippet)` on the snippet above, the cursor is not positioned correctly.

---

Here where it ***should*** jump:

Press tab 1st: Make whole line `${1: :var: name="$2"}` because it can be optional

Press tab 2nd: Make only "$2" in the line `${1: :var: name="$2"}`.

Press tab 3rd: Make whole line `${3: :var: url="$4"}` because it can be optional

... and so on

Here's what it ***actually***  does:

Press tab 1st: Make whole line `${1: :var: name="$2"}` because it can be optional

Press tab 2nd: Make whole line `${3: :var: url="$4"}`

---

The problem seem to be produced by the `:var:` Keyword.

It stops yasnippet from jumping to the `$2`. If I change it to only `var:` or `:var` it will work. But then it won't be able to include these properties into a src code block and work with it.
It will also work if I remove the quotes from the placeholder. So this will work, but as before, then I cannot eval the url var in code blocks

```
${3: :var: url=$4}
```

I also tried excaping things with no luck:

```
${3: :var: url=\"$4\"}
or
${3: :var: url='$4'}
or
${3: \:var\: url="$4"}
```

Any ideas on how to write this snippet or what I'm doing wrong.